# How to turn-off timer set by <meta> tag

Tags: html

i have set timer for refreshing my page for every 10 sec using meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com" />`.
But in some case i need to turn that timer off .How i could turn the meta timer

Comment: add that meta tag with jquery

Comment: You could get all instances of `<meta` elements on the page, before removing one if it has an attribute named 'http-equiv', whose value was 'refresh'. As webo80 was getting at, it's an easier proposition to add the tag for all other cases, rather than remove it for some. Removal involves finding elements, looking for particular attributes and then ensuring a matching value. Adding the tag involves simply creating a meta element, setting attribs and adding it to the page's head. I've not checked, but assume that adding a meta tag after the page has loaded would not interfere with the refresh.